# Android shape doesn't stretch as progressDrawable on seekbar

Tags: android

I use a vertical Seekbar library as a Color Picker. I managed to set the ProgressDrawable as a shape with gradient that represent the Colors of the seekbar.

```
LinearGradient test = new LinearGradient(0.f, conv.toPixels(170), 0.0f, 0.0f,
                new int[]{0xFF000050, 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF00FF00, 0xFF00FFFF,
                        0xFFFF0000, 0xFFFF00FF, 0xFFFFFF00, 0xFFFFFFFF},
                null, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        ShapeDrawable shape = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
        shape.getPaint().setShader(test);
```

Here I am creating the gradient and parse him as a Shape.After this I set the shape as ProgressDrawable of the seekbar.

```
    colorSeekbar.setMax(252 - 1);
    colorSeekbar.setProgressDrawable(shape);
```

Finally I add my seekbar:

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(conv.toPixels(80), conv.toPixels(200));
    params.setMargins(conv.toPixels(5), conv.toPixels(5), conv.toPixels(5), conv.toPixels(5));

    colorSeekbar.setThumb(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.seek_thumb_color, null));
    colorSeekbar.setOrientation(UniversalSeekBar.BOTTOM_TO_TOP);

    popUpBulbContainer.addView(colorSeekbar, params);
```

[image]

The red background is the background of the `seekbar`.The gradient is the `progressDrawable` and the blue background is the background of a Horizontal `LinearLayout` that hold all the views.
You can notice the thumb being set on the top of the seekbar where the `progressDrawable` can't get there.
Any Ideea how can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayout seems correct. It must be something to do with your parent layout in activity layout file.

If you are adding all those elements programatically make sure you attach the elements (popUpBulbContainer) to the top layout of the activity.

Comment: Yes everything is done programatically, the parent is a a popUp.

Comment: Try setting popUp layout as a FrameLayout with wrap-content width and height and gravity set to center